# NumPy matrix multiplication with @ in pythontex

Tags: python, pythontex

The following commands are working fine in Python 3.x:

```py
import numpy as np
M = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
D = np.diag([1,2,3])
M@D
```

But, when I use `pythontex`, I get an error with `M@D`. Do you know why?

[image: error screenshot]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{pythontex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{pyconsole}
import numpy as np
M = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
D = np.diag([1,2,3])
M@D
\end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

I typeset my .tex file with 
`xelatex -8bit filename / pythontex filename / xelatex -8bit filename`

Comment: Could be a missing `\makeatletter` - `\makeatother` or Python version problem. Without an MWE is difficult to say...

Comment: My message contains now a MWE.

Comment: I tried to add the option `--interpreter python:python3` to pythontex, but it doesn't fix the issue (and I think that since the last version of Pythontex, the default interpreter is Python 3).

Comment: This works fine for me with the latest pythontex.  So we need to know more about the versions you have and how you run pythontex.

Comment: I use the following commands : `xelatex -8bit filename` / `pythontex filename` / `xelatex -8bit filename`

Comment: Pythontex version : the last one. Python : Anaconda Python 3.7.4

Comment: That combination works of commands works for me without syntax error.  The syntax hightlighting is off, but is fixed by writing `M @ D` with spaces.  Can you add `\listfiles` to your latex file and should the resulting list of package versions  from the log file.

Comment: Finally the spaces fix the issue, if I typeset with the commands `xelatex -8bit filename` / `pythontex filename` / `xelatex -8bit filename`in a shell. Unfortunately, by using my TeX editor (TeXpad), I get always the error.

Comment: `**...
(/Users/jowe_19/Desktop/pythontex_caract.tex
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pythontex/pythontex.sty
Package: pythontex 2019/09/22 v0.17 execute and typeset Python code and other languages
\openout4 = `pythontex_caract.pytxcode'.
) (./pythontex_caract.aux)
\openout1 = `pythontex_caract.aux'.
 (./pythontex-files-pythontex_caract/pythontex_caract.pytxmcr)
 (./pythontex-files-pythontex_caract/pythontex_caract.pytxpyg)
] (./pythontex_caract.aux)
pythontex.sty    2019/09/22 v0.17 execute and typeset Python code and other languages.`

Comment: Thank you - some of this information should be edited in to your question.  Anyway, it sounds like you need to check the paths and environment that TeXpad uses to call the compilation commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed the issue by adding `source ~/.zshrc` at the beginning of the tpbuild script used by Texpad for typesetting. The PATH used by TexPad is now correct.